# Have to apply CSS from a hosting site through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe, and onLoad am applying css through javascript.  This iframe contains data from website A and hosted on website B.  The javascript that applies css will be included in the iframe and the css values (to change color of html elements) will be passed by website B.

I have written javascript and like this; please help if there are any suggestions to achieve this or any improvements will be appreciated.

The script on SiteA:-
    /* this variable values will be set by site B */

JS

```
var iframeCSSParams = {
    links: "blue",
    companyName: "blue",
    searchButtonColor: "darkcyan",
    fontsColor: "blue"
    so on..
};

function applycss(iframe, CSSParams) {

    var linksColor = CSSParams.links;
    var companyNameColor = CSSParams.companyName;
    var searchButtonColor = CSSParams.searchButtonColor;
    jQuery(iframe).contents().find('.alinks').css('color', linksColor);
    jQuery(iframe).contents().find('.p-company-name').css('color', companyNameColor);
    and so on...
}

function Iframe_Load(iframe) {
    try {
        var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        applycss(iframe, iframeCSSParams);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('exception: ' + e);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="listFrame" scrolling="NO" style="padding:0; width:626px;" frameborder="0"
  src="/siteA/search" onload="Iframe_Load(this)" />
```

Comment: Are you saying your existing code works but you're wondering if there's a better way, or that your existing code doesn't work and you need help to fix it?

Comment: the code I have written, works.  But I am new to javascript front end; am not sure if there can be better ways to do it.